# Can someone help me with this limit of sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

This is a question from my homework that I do not know how to approach it. Please help!

Find the limit of the sequence as n approaches infinity
$$a_n = \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^3+9n}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to click the check mark, but it keeps say "you can accept an answer in 4 minutes", what should i do then?

Comment: wait for 4 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let us make some operation, but  please  after  find you answer accept it,first let us  take out   n out of brackets,we would have 
$n^2/\sqrt{n*({9+n^2})}$,after  you get here,you can cancel out  both side by  $\sqrt{n}$,we get  $n*\sqrt(n) /(\sqrt{9+n^2})$,take  n in radical  ,you get

$\sqrt{n^3}/(\sqrt{9+n^2})$,remember that $\sqrt{a/b}= \sqrt{a}/(\sqrt{b})$ and finally  you get that answer is +infinity,because in numerator degree is bigger than in denumenator

Answer (score 2):

See that $$a_n=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{1+9/n^2}}$$
Clearly the limit is infintity!

Comment: I think you meant $+\infty$...

Comment: I apologise for that!

Answer (score 1):

Informally and intuitively, limit to infinity can always be thought of as limit to some very large number. If n were very large $n^3$ would be much larger than $9n$, hence denominator would be approx $n^{1.5}$, hence whole fraction that is $a_n$ would be $n^{0.5}$ which would be infinitely large if n were infinitely large. Also sqaure root could be both +ve and -ve, so $a_n$ could be approaching both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.